# how to set django admin ordering field customely?

Tags: python, django

admin.py

```
class MovieItemInline(AjaxSelectAdminTabularInline):
    model = MovieItem
    ordering = ['-date']


class MovielistAdmin(ModelAdminBase, AjaxSelectAdmin):
    inlines = (MovieItemInline, )


admin.site.register(Movielist, MovielistAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class MovieItem(Model):
    title = CharField(default="")
    view_number = IntegerField(default=0)
    price = IntegerField(default=0)
    date = IntegerField(default=0)


class Movielist(Model):
    title = CharField(default="")
    display_order = CharField(default="date")
```

MovieItemInline is MovielistAdmin's inline attribute,
I wanna sort MovieItem, for example,
if Movielist.display_order equals "date", then sort MovieItem by MovieItem.date.
if Movielist.display_order equals "price", then sort MovieItem by MovieItem.price.
if Movielist.display_order equals "view_number", then sort MovieItem by MovieItem.view_number.
What should I do?
Is django support?

Comment: I have same question.

Comment: Did the below answer helped you to resolve your issue?

Comment: @nik_m, sorry, no.

Comment: Why is that? It should be. I tested it locally and it works fine. Do you get any error or something?

Comment: @nik_m, it worked. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [`get_ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_ordering) method inside `MovieItemInline` class.

```
from django.urls import resolve

def get_ordering(self, request):
    # get Movielist object instance from request
    object_id = resolve(request.path).args[0]
    
    # retrieve Movielist object 
    movie_list = MovieList.objects.get(id=object_id)

    # modify ordering based on movie_list display_order value
    if movie_list.display_order == 'date':
        return ['-date']
    elif movie_list.display_order == 'price':
        return ['-price']
    elif movie_list.display_order == 'view_number':
        return ['-view_number']

    # fallback value if non of the above match
    return ['-title']
```